# Addthis, localize captcha reading?

Tags: javascript, localization, addthis

I'm using addthis widget to share a custom url like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-56bb21874c1c3e28" async="async"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            /*  INFO AQUÍ http://www.addthis.com/academy/email-templates/ */ 
            var addthis_share = { 
                email_template: "KIP_template",
                email_vars: { 
                    trans_url: "<?=base_url('area-privada/comprador/inicio/'.$id)?>", 
                    trans_name: "<?php echo $title ?>" 
                }
            }
</script>
```

But before sending to email, there's a captcha:

[image]

That when clicked in the mike icon, it plays the sound:

[image]

The problem is that the voice is Latin america Spanish, we need Spain spanish,

Is there any way to localize that?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the AddThis documentation? Seems like you can configure a global `addthis_config` object, in which you can configure the language. http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381240-languages

Comment: Yes, but if you notice; they have listed just one spanish... does that mean that's it? Latin spanish?

Comment: Oh, that is unfortunate – I think your question is better directed at AddThis support